# Text-Based RPG, start tile location keeps showing as NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have what is hopefully my final question on this project (probably not, but lets just go with it). I've set up my map in such a way that I can expand or contract it any time I want, without having to reset the player's starting position in the Player class. However, it appears that no matter what changes I make, at runtime the program is attempting to drop a player into a NoneType tile while will crash the game because NoneType tiles don't have any text in them.

I tried changing the indexes on the

```
self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
```

in my Player class but to no avail. I also verified that the code for the world map matches what was written in the book that I am following along with.

Here is the code for the world map:

```
world_dsl = """
    |EN|EN|VT|EN|EN|
    |EN|  |  |  |EN|
    |EN|FG|EN|  |TT|
    |TT|  |ST|FG|EN|
    |FG|  |EN|  |FG|
"""
def is_dsl_valid(dsl):
    if dsl.count("|ST|") != 1:
        return False
    if dsl.count("|VT|") == 0:
        return False
    lines = dsl.splitlines()
    lines = [l for l in lines if l]
    pipe_counts = [line.count("|") for line in lines]
    for count in pipe_counts:
        if count != pipe_counts[0]:
            return False

    return True

tile_type_dict = {"VT": VictoryTile,
                  "EN": EnemyTile,
                  "ST": StartTile,
                  "FG": FindGoldTile,
                  "TT": TraderTile,
                  "  ": None}


world_map = []

start_tile_location = None

def parse_world_dsl():
    if not is_dsl_valid(world_dsl):
        raise SyntaxError("DSL is invalid!")

    dsl_lines = world_dsl.splitlines()
    dsl_lines = [x for x in dsl_lines if x]

    for y, dsl_row in enumerate(dsl_lines):
        row = []
        dsl_cells = dsl_row.split("|")
        dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c.strip()]
        for x, dsl_cell in enumerate(dsl_cells):
            tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
            if tile_type == StartTile:
                global start_tile_location
                start_tile_location = x, y
                row.append(tile_type(x, y) if tile_type else None)

            world_map.append(row)
```

And then the code that uses this in the Player class:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = [items.Rock(),
                          items.Dagger(),
                          items.CrustyBread()]
        self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
        self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
        self.hp = 100
        self.gold = 5
        self.victory = False
```

If you need more of the source code in order to debug the issue, let me know.

Error that it throws is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'intro_text'` which I know means that it's attempting to drop the player into a location that is a `NoneType`. Just not sure what I missed.

Also, I know global variables are frowned upon, but I used one here for two reasons:

1. It is getting called only once in the program, and we know that the start tile will never need to change.
2. The book said to :P

Edit: As a side note, I DID pass the parse_world_dsl function before I create the player object in the main game file. I know this is important, and it was one of the first things I checked but *shrug*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show a bit more code? Specifically the line that's causing the error and a few lines around it.

In any case, your `parse_world_dsl` function seems to have some indentation issues. Here is what I believe it should look like (notice, I only changed two lines. I moved the `row.append(...)` out of the if-statement into the inner for-loop, and I moved the `world_map.append(...)` out of the inner for-loop into the outer for-loop):

```
def parse_world_dsl():
    if not is_dsl_valid(world_dsl):
        raise SyntaxError("DSL is invalid!")

    dsl_lines = world_dsl.splitlines()
    dsl_lines = [x for x in dsl_lines if x]

    for y, dsl_row in enumerate(dsl_lines):
        row = []
        dsl_cells = dsl_row.split("|")
        dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c.strip()]
        for x, dsl_cell in enumerate(dsl_cells):
            tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
            if tile_type == StartTile:
                global start_tile_location
                start_tile_location = x, y
            row.append(tile_type(x, y) if tile_type else None)

        world_map.append(row)
```

You want to append the current tile to the current row regardless of whether or not it's a StartTile. You also want to append the current row once for each iteration of the outer for-loop.

However, even with that fix, your world_map would look something like this:

```
[EN, EN, VT, EN, EN]
[EN, EN]
[EN, FG, EN, TT]
[TT, ST, FG, EN]
[FG, EN, FG]
```

Since the temporary list `dsl_cells` in your first for-loop only consists of cells that are not blank. The blank ones are lost because you only keep the ones where `.strip()`ing the current cell does not evaluate to an empty, falsey string. Not sure if that was deliberate on your part, which is why it would be helpful to see the line of code that's actually causing the error.

Comment: Haha yeah, indentation errors seem to be my bread and butter with python. Fixing the indents actually fixed the code. Thanks so much for your help!